# count size array show in order S to L

Tags: jquery

```
function checkmysize(){
    var values = [];
    var total = {};
    var total_html ="";
    var inputs = $('.size-col');
    var total_content = $('#size-count-content');

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        values.push($(inputs[i]).val());
    }
    for (var j = 0, v = values.length; j < v; j++) {
        total[values[j]] = (total[values[j]] || 0) + 1;
    }
    total_html += "<div id='total-list'><p>"+JSON.stringify(total)+"</p></div>";
    $('#size-count-content').append(total_html);
}
```

i am making a count size check , so basic is user choice all the size they need and show it the total size they had choice, but i want the size show in order , start from "S , M , L" but my array show it mixed , how to i make my array show it in order.

check here to understand more , thank. change the option
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/wgbopaty/)

Comment: so values is an array containing "S M and L" right

Comment: well the values is empty at first.

Comment: i want it to show like S , M , L no matter which value in option push in array first.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
{
var values = ['M','L','S']; //your array which needs sorting
//sorting reference array
var sizes = { 
       "S": 0, "M": 1, "L": 2
    };
    var compareA;
    var compareB;

values.sort(function(a,b){  
 compareA = sizes[a];
 compareB = sizes[b];

 return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
  });
console.log(values);

};
```

Comment: how do i make it work with my code , i cant make it work. thank